# ES6 React JSX returns an object instead of array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

After playing around with react I noticed a strange behavior while outputting array:

```js
function bar1() {
  let arr = [0, 1];
  return arr.map((el) => foo(el))
}

function bar2() {
  let arr = [0, 1];
  arr = arr.map((el) => foo(el))
  return (
    {arr}
  )
}

function foo(key) {
  return (
    <div key={key}>Foo</div>
    )
}
```

I would expect bar1() and bar2() to output identical results, however bar2() throws error:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {arr}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

I need to insert additional element in bar2() after map operation, that's why i can't use the simplified version.

Is it a bug related to JSX or it behaves as expected?

Comment: That error is self explanatory. React can't render Objects in render output.

Comment: Remove the brackets. arr != {arr}

Comment: It doesn't give me error in JSfiddle... https://jsfiddle.net/psiho/gL05ddfg/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question - it's not a bug, it's an expected behavior.

When you return `{arr}`, you essentially return a `{arr: arr}` object because Babel understands it as an ES6 object shorthand (see [property definition](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Object_initializerhttps://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Object_initializer)). In order to have the same output from both of your functions, you should remove the curly braces from your `bar2()` function's return statement.